# Python Simple server-client

Tags: python, server, client

I'm having some trouble with a project I'm working on for my networking class. I'm supposed to make a server-client RPS game and send the throw choice via HTTP messages.
I'm trying to figure out how to get my server to serve to other IPs outside my localhost. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!

Here is the code

SERVER:

````
```import sys
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

newgame = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors']

# setup echoHandler to allow server to run

class echoHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path.endswith('/'):
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('content-type', 'text/html')
            self.end_headers()


#HTML code for basic webpage 


            output = ''
            output += '<html><body>'
            output += 'Your move options are:'
            output += '<h1> Rock, Paper, Scissors</h1>'
            output += 'Please send your response... and one more thing'
            output += '<h3> GOOD LUCK BEATING ME BLAKE</h3>'
            output += "<h2>Please select a move</h2>"
            for game in newgame:
                output += game
                output += '</br>'
            output += '</body></html>'
# Not sure if professor will allow a form and submit combo, ask in office hours.

            # output += ''
            # output += '<html><body>'
            # output += '<h1> Enter your play</h1>'
            # output += '<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action=/newgame/new">'
            # output += '<input name="move" type="text" placeholder="Enter move">'
            # output += '<input type="submit" value="add">'
            # output += '</form>'
            # output += '</body>'

            self.wfile.write(output.encode())



# define main to run program and take arguments for IP and Port

def main():
    PORT = 8000
    server = HTTPServer((sys.argv[1], PORT), echoHandler)
    print('Server running on port %s' % PORT)
    server.serve_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main() ```
````

And here is the CLIENT:

````
```import socket
import sys


justin = sys.argv[1]
port = int(sys.argv[2])
portClient = int(sys.argv[3])
class Client:
# create the server bind and connection from CL

    HEADERSIZE = 10
    server = (sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2]))
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((justin, portClient))
    s.connect(((sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2])))  #connect (ipadress, port)
    message = input("->")

# receive messages from server side

    while True:
        s.sendto(message.encode('utf-8'), server)
        data, addr = s.recvfrom(1234)
        data = data.decode('utf-8')
        print("received from server: " + data)
        message = input("->")
    sys.exit

    print(full_msg)```
````